# How to create interrupt screen in game?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, popup, interrupt

In games, I see there are some kind of popup view will appear (on which have buttons for pausing, saving and quitting) if there is an interruption during game play in iphone.

1) How to create it and invoke such in code?

I have been searching for weeks on web, the documentation, forum, etc and still couldn't find the solution. All I can find are only something close - Tutorials show how to implement a 2nd view which is invoked by pressing a button on main view but that is not what I need.

2) What does that kind of view is called? For sure I know it is not called splash, opening screen. Is it called "interrupt screen, pausing screen or setting screen?

3) The following method can only be implemented in UIViewController class to bring up the 2nd view using a button (that is not what I want) and my game is using customized UIView and it can't invoke the method.

> -(void)goToSecondView{
>   [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
>   }

4) I got an advice using @protocol but it is a bit advanced for me to understand. Is there some easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you call such a screen, you should do this:

1. Accept some of the answers to your previous questions here on Stack Overflow.
2. Pause your game.
3. Create a `UIView` that you want to show, either programmatically or by loading it from a NIB file.
4. Present it by calling `-addSubview:`. Optionally, animate it into position with the `UIView` animation methods.